# Multinomial permutation indexing

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, multinomial-coefficients

There are 6!=720 permutations of {1,2,3,4,5,6}.  Using [Lehmer codes](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PermutationsLehmerCodeAndLexicographicIndex/) each permutation has a lexicographic index.

There are 6!/(3! 3!)=20 permutations of {0,0,0,1,1,1}. Is there a way to index these in a way similar to the lexicographic index?  Is there some sort of system related to [simplex coordinates](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:8_choose_3_array_with_simplex_coordinates.svg)?

Of the binary numbers up to $2^{100}-1$, exactly ${100}\choose{7}$ =16007560800 of them have exactly seven 1's. Which of these numbers has index 8000000000?

Does it help that there are exactly as many 8-part integer partitions of 101?

```
Total[(Multinomial @@ Tally[#][[All, 2]]) & /@ IntegerPartitions[101, {8}]]
```

The integer partitions before {32,21,16,11,10,7,3,1} are 6416 short of 8000000000, so I suppose taking the 6416th permutation of that would give the gaps between the ones in one indexing system. But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Do you mean a kind of indexing which allows an easy computation of a permutation from its index?

Comment: Yes, but effective is better than easy.  The easy solution is to generate 2^100 binary numbers, pick out those with binary sum 7, and go to the one with index 8 billion.  But no computer can do that at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clasify these sort of structures using pascal's triangle (recursively) . We have $C^{a}_{b} = C^{a-1}_{b} + C^{a-1}_{b-1}$ . Every number $n$ from $1$ to $C^{a}_{b}$ can be decomposed as: $$n = \sum_{t=b..s} C^{k_t}_{t}$$ 
with  $k_s = s$ and $k_t > k_{t-1}$ and $s \leq b$ . This would correspond to the digit sequence where the digits indexed by $k_t + 1, t\neq s$, and the first $s$ digits would be $1$ and the rest would be $0$. The ordering would be in terms of increasing binary numbers (natural ordering). Let's apply this to $8000000000$ and ${100}\choose{7}$. 
$$8000000000 = {{90}\choose{7}} + {{87}\choose{6}}  +{{79}\choose{5}} + {{73}\choose{4}}  + {{47}\choose{3}} + {{42}\choose{2}} + {{40}\choose{1}} + {{0}\choose{0}}$$
Note that ${{0}\choose{0}}$ is here defined as $0$ in order to maintain the recurrence relation. In conclusion, corresponding to the 8000000000 index would be the binary number who's $1$ digits are indexed by $\{91,88,80,74,48,43,41\}$. When decomposing the number into a sum of combinations, we must always choose the maximum $k_t$ of $C^{k_t}_{t}$ such that the remainder is positive (excluding the case where $t=1$ or $k_t = t$, when we will have remainder 0) . Eg: $2 = {{7}\choose{7}} + {{6}\choose{6}}$ means the 8'th digit and the first 6 digits will be $0$, giving 10111111.

---

Edit: adding answer to " What year does this date back to? Is there a multinomial version for permutations of $\{0,0,1,1,2,2,2\}$?"

I'm sure someone's used this algorithm before, but I've just made it up on the fly. I couldn't find any reference. If you can order and count something, you can index it. I will do a rough outline of the algorithm for $\{0,0,1,1,2,2,2\}$

Let's take again the natural order in base "3". There's a total of $\frac{7!}{3!2!2!} = 210$ numbers formed by permuting the digits $\{0,0,1,1,2,2,2\}$ . Let's say we're given a random index $0<n\leq 210$ and our aim is to construct the corresponding number. First we determine what is the $7$'th digit of our number (counted right to left, aka. the $7$'th digit is the left-most digit), as there are a total of 7 digits. It can be either $0$,$1$, or $2$. The $7$'th digit is the most significant for our ordering.

Numbers with the $7$'th digit $0$  are smaller than numbers with $7$'th digit $1$  are smaller than numbers with $7$'th digit $2$ (we have $0...$ < $1...$ < $2...$ ). So those ending with $0$ are counted first, followed by those with $1$, followed by those with $2$. There are $\frac{6!}{3!2!1!} = 60$ numbers with $7$'th digit $0$,   $\frac{6!}{3!1!2!} = 60$ numbers with $7$'th digit $1$ and $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!} = 90$ numbers with $7$'th digit $2$. A total of $210$ numbers. Arranged ascendantly, this splits $(0,210]$ in $\{(0,60],60 + (0,60],60+60 + (0,90]\} =\{(0,60], (60,120], (120,210]\}$. These are the intervals of the indices of the numbers who's $7$'th digit is $0$, $1$ and $2$. We find out to which one of these intervals $(a,k+a]$ does our $n$ belong to, make a note the corresponding $7$'th digit, then "forget" it: we do this by considering the remaining six digits as being indexed by $n-a$, from $(0,k]$ and applying the formula recursively for these remaining $6$ digits.

Comment: That's brilliant.  What year does this date back to?  
Is there a multinomial version for permutations of {0,0,1,1,2,2,2}?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include an outline of the multinational version.

Comment: IMO it would be worth replacing all references to the 7th digit with "most significant digit". That exposes the generality of the technique, which is the standard technique for indexing any combinatorial object which is counted recursively.

Comment: "the standard technique for indexing any combinatorial object which is counted recursively". Do you have a reference? I could not find one. I was hesitant to use "most significant digit" because here the leading digit can be $0$, whereas in normal counting $0$ would not be considered significant (ie. the most significant digit of 00200) is the third digit, $2$.

Comment: I don't have a reference, but I have also independently invented the same approach, and I've seen many other people do likewise on this site and on codegolf.stackexchange.com, particularly for indexing partitions and rooted trees. The reason that "most significant digit" is not problematic is that we're not dealing with numbers but lists / tuples / ordered sequences. Well, perhaps "most significant element" would be more accurate.

Comment: @EdPegg, if you can get your hands on [*Bijective Combinatorics* by Nicholas Loehr](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/nloehr/bijbook.html) then the description of the contents ("*We present systematic techniques for [ranking and unranking] based on bijective versions of the sum and product rules*") suggests that chapter 5 might serve as a reference, or if you're lucky even give you some journal paper references.